# eajaxupload in yii failes

Tags: upload, yii-extensions

I try ti user eajaxupload extention in yii(using this article: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eajaxupload

I want Upload and attache image to one of controller,
I try this code:
**in controller:** **(my controller name is : article)**

```
public function actionUpload()
        {
    Yii::import("ext.EAjaxUpload.qqFileUploader");

        $folder= Yii::app()->baseUrl .'/uploads';// folder for uploaded files
        $allowedExtensions = array("jpg");//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
        $sizeLimit = 10 * 1024 * 1024;// maximum file size in bytes

        $uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
        $result = $uploader->handleUpload($folder);
        $result=htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);

    $fileSize=filesize($folder.$result['filename']);//GETTING FILE SIZE
        $fileName=$result['filename'];//GETTING FILE NAME

        //echo $result;// it's array
    }
```

and in _form.php (for controller) i have:

```
$this->widget('ext.EAjaxUpload.EAjaxUpload',
        array(
            'id'=>'uploadFile',
                'config'=>array(
                    'action'=>'/article/upload',
                    'allowedExtensions'=>array("jpg"),//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
                    'sizeLimit'=>10*1024*1024,// maximum file size in bytes
                    //'minSizeLimit'=>10*1024*1024,// minimum file size in bytes
                    //'onComplete'=>"js:function(id, fileName, responseJSON){ alert(fileName); }",

                    'showMessage'=>"js:function(message){ alert(message); }"
                    )
)); ?>
```

upload folder have full access for all!,
but when i push upload file and select a file always get error: filename, filesize and **Faild!**

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

What do you see on the console when you you add this

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";exit(0);
```

after $result=htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);

Comment: I have the same problem and here is the console output 
POST request : 
qq.extend._upload fileuploader.js:1204
qq.UploadHandlerAbstract.upload fileuploader.js:892
qq.FileUploaderBasic._uploadFile fileuploader.js:397
qq.FileUploaderBasic._uploadFileList fileuploader.js:388
qq.FileUploaderBasic._onInputChange fileuploader.js:372
qq.UploadButton.onChange fileuploader.js:309
(anonymous function)

Comment: Then I got a get request with the following output
send jquery.js:8434
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7986
reloadImagesArea 551?required=1:934
qq.FileUploader.onComplete 551?required=1:1109
qq.(anonymous function).onComplete fileuploader.js:333
qq.extend._onComplete fileuploader.js:1230
xhr.onreadystatechange

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your upload folder exists. Yii::app()->baseUrl returns '...yourproject/protected'.

I use:`$folder=Yii::app() -> getBasePath() . "/../images/";`

Also check your console in browser(press F12). If you got 403 error, then add rules to your controller for upload action

```
    public function accessRules()
    {
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view','upload'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ), 
     .....
```